# Can't get push notifications to go through Firebase

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am trying to enable push notifications on my app. I have done this process at least 30 times with no luck. I will list out the exact steps I took.

1. Under capabilities in my xcode project I went ahead and enabled push notifications which automatically created an app id. I also enabled background modes and remote notifications.
2. I went to developer.apple.com and directed to my app id page. I saw the app id that was created and saw push notifications was configurable. So I open my keychain access and request a certificate from the certificate authority. I end up with the `.certSigningRequest`.
3. I then take that file and upload it to the development push notification SSL certificate and I am left with a `.cer` file which I open and saves onto keychain access. I see this `Apple Development IOS Push Services: com.mybundleidentifier`
4. I then export that as a .p12 file and upload it to Firebase.
5. I then write the code to allow for push notifications and accept it on my REAL device, not the simulator.

   ```
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
           (granted, error) in
           print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
       }
   ```
6. I go to the background i.e. my home screen. I try to send a notification....and fail don't see anything on my device.

Comment: Where have you send the recieved device token to the firebase?

Comment: I dont need the user token mainly cause there is a feature in firebase that lets you send a notification to every user with the app.

Comment: Follow with simple steps once https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/

Comment: I followed that tutorial exactly more than once still no luck

Comment: @joethemow: Got it, actually Firebase is swizzling Appdelegate's methods. I would advise you to disable swizzling in Firebase and debug whether you are recieving device token from APNS or not and if you are receiving, you can send that device token to Firebase through one of their methods as well.

Comment: So I am able to print the device token `if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }`

Comment: @joethemow: I am unaware of firebase but there are actually two types of push notification certificates that can be generated. One is production, other one is development. I hope you are using the correct certificate to send the push. When you are running the app in debug mode then development certifcate will work.

Comment: Yup using development cert and debug mode.